# browsermob-proxy get .har file and permission denied

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get work with your gem and in windows 7 I did the following:

```
gem install browsermob-proxy
```

all went with success
but then I try to launch code:

```
require 'selenium/webdriver'
require 'browsermob/proxy'

server = BrowserMob::Proxy::Server.new('C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/browsermob-proxy-0.1.3/lib/browsermob-proxy.rb') #=> #<BrowserMob::Proxy::Server:0x000001022c6ea8 ...>
server.start

proxy = server.create_proxy #=> #<BrowserMob::Proxy::Client:0x0000010224bdc0 ...>

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new #=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile:0x000001022bf748 ...>
profile.proxy = proxy.selenium_proxy

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile

proxy.new_har "google"
driver.get "http://google.com"

har = proxy.har #=> #<HAR::Archive:0x-27066c42d7e75fa6>
har.entries.first.request.url #=> "http://google.com"
har.save_to "/tmp/google.har"

proxy.close
driver.quit
```

and get error:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/browsermob-proxy-0.1.3/lib/browsermob/proxy/server.rb:16:in ´initialize' : Permission denied - not executable: C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/browsermob-proxy-0.1.3/lib/browsermob-proxy.rb (Errno::EACCES) 
from gethar.rb:in 'new'
from gethar.rb:in '<main>'
```

I thought that there are no permissions in windows like in linux?
So any help please

Answer (score 1):

The error message is misleading. This isn't a permissions issue; you need to point to the browsermob bat file, which is separate from the gem.

You can download it here: http://bmp.lightbody.net/

Then point to the file location, mine looks like this:

```
server = BrowserMob::Proxy::Server.new('C:/browsermob-proxy/bin/browsermob-proxy.bat')
```

That should fix your problem.